# Why does $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, cauchy-product

Having  $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n!}z^n$

I had to find what $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n!}z^n\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{D_n}{n!}z^n=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} z^n$ was and it seems that it is

$$e^zf(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$$

I understand the left size of the equation (even though I only feel that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n!}z^n=e^z$)  but I don't understand the right one.

**Thus why does $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}$**

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: You understand the infinite series for $e^z$, but the geometric series puzzles you? I would not have thought this was possible.

Comment: We used it in course

Comment: So, what kind of course teaches the infinite series for $e^z$ to students who haven't learned how to sum a geometric series?

Answer (score 1):

This is true only if $\lvert z\rvert <1$. The reason is quite simple and relies on a well known identity from high school:
$$1-z^n=(1-z)(1+z+z^2+\dots+z^{n-1})$$
which we can rewrite as
$$\frac1{1-z}=1+z+z^2+\dots+z^{n-1}+\frac{z^n}{1-z}.$$
From this we deduce that 
$$\biggl\lvert\frac1{1-z}-(1+z+z^2+\dots+z^{n-1})\biggr\rvert=\frac{\bigl\lvert z\rvert^n}{\lvert 1-z\rvert}\to 0\quad\text{as}\enspace n\to\infty.$$